# FragmentStatePageAdapter won't refresh when calling notifydatasetchanged()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have an activity with a ViewPager and a Spinner and all I want to do is a change all pages content by selecting items in Spinner, to be more fully understood I'll explain - I am developing a simple TV-schedule weekly programm, so pages is a daily tv-programms and spinner is a tv-channels and when we've launch a programm it will display a short 4-items programm list for all channels and when we selected a "CNN" or whatever elese in spinner it will display a fully TV-programm list for a day which page is displaying(for displaying a days i use a TitlePageIndicator), so my problem is when I've selected an item in spinner, have loaded a data and have
called a notifydatasetchanged() for my FragmentStatePagerAdapter - it won't refresh a pages. I didn't get what I am doing wrong?

MyAdapter

```
private class TVProgrammFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private FragmentManager fm;
    private ArrayList<TVProgrammFragment> mFragments;

    public TVProgrammFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<TVProgrammFragment> mFragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
        this.mFragments = mFragments;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return ((TVProgrammFragment) mFragments.get(position)).getTitle();
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return mFragments.get(arg0);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

            // I don't know wherefore this line
            // It is a first issue that I've googled
            // And it's useless
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

Some code from MyActivity onCreate

```
mAdapter = new TVProgrammFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), new ArrayList<TVProgrammFragment>());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setTopPadding(0);
    mIndicator.setSelectedBold(true);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            if (mChannelIndex != position) {
                String param = position == 0 ? String.valueOf(mTVProgrammAdapter.dates.get(mPager.getCurrentItem()).date) : String.valueOf(mTVProgrammAdapter.dates.get(mPager.getCurrentItem()).date) + "/" + String.valueOf(mTVProgrammAdapter.channels.get(position).id);
                 //Problems are here -->
                setParamsToPages(param);
                 //<--
                mChannelIndex = position;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    getTVProgrammDatesChannels();
```

And this is how I getting the data after app's launch

```
 //LoadHelper it is a class which does all data-loading things from server API
 //And it works perfectly with any problems
 LoadHelper.getTVProgrammDatesAndChannels(new OnLoadFinishedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(final Object obj) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mTVProgrammAdapter = ((TVProgrammAdapter) obj);
                    mTVProgrammAdapter.channels.add(0, new TVProgrammChannel("-1", ALL_CHANNELS));
                    mTVChannelsAdapter = new ChannelsAdapter(mTVProgrammAdapter.channels);
                    mSpinner.setAdapter(mTVChannelsAdapter);

                   //Setting a pages for a dates
                    for (TVProgrammDate date : mTVProgrammAdapter.dates) {
                        TVProgrammFragment tvFragmemnt = new TVProgrammFragment();
                        tvFragmemnt.setArguments(date);
                        ((TVProgrammFragmentAdapter) mPager.getAdapter()).mFragments.add(tvFragmemnt);
                    }

                    ((TVProgrammFragmentAdapter) mPager.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
                }
            });
        }
```

And here goes my problems - is a setParamsToPages method

```
    public void setParamsToPages(final String param) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final ArrayList<TVProgrammFragment> fragments = ((TVProgrammFragmentAdapter) mPager.getAdapter()).mFragments;

            //Here I setting a new fragments with new params to 
            //TVProgrammFragmentAdapter fragments ArrayList(mFragments)

            for (TVProgrammFragment tvFragmemnt : fragments) {
                TVProgrammFragment newFragment = new TVProgrammFragment();
                String title = tvFragmemnt.getTitle();
                newFragment.setArguments(title, param);
                fragments.set(fragments.indexOf(tvFragmemnt), newFragment);
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //doesn't do anything
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            //mAdapter still displaying an "old"
                                            //fragments
                }

            });
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I forgot to start a thread LOL!=)